# Всплывающая подсказка, не выходящая за границы экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

### Вопрос

Что нужно сделать, дабы тултипы никогда не вылазили сверху, снизу, слева, справа? На экранах как телефонов, так и компьютеров?

### Попытки решения

- [**Всплывающая подсказка на CSS**](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/vsplyvayushchaya-podskazka-na-css)
- [**Тултипы на CSS3 и HTML5**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/132283/)

Не подошло. Ниже одна из неудачных попыток: как видно, всплывающая подсказка обрезается сверху.

```css
a.SashaLove {
  color: #fff; 
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgb(212,75,56);
  outline: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-style: outset;
  border-color: Bisque;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 60px rgba(0,0,0,0) inset;
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  -o-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
} 
a.SashaLove:hover  {
  color: #fff; 
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgb(212,75,56);
  outline: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  -o-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;}
a.SashaLove:active {
  color: #fff; 
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgb(212,75,56);
  outline: none;
  font-size: 28px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  -o-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 200px rgba(0,0,0,.09) inset;
}
.SashaOrchidea {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.SashaOrchidea:hover::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  position: absolute; 
    left: 20%; bottom: 30%; 
    z-index: 1; 
    outline: none;
    line-height: 1;
    background: Bisque;
    font-family: "sans-serif"; 
    font-size: 30px; 
    padding: 10px 10px; 
    border: 1px solid #333; 
    color: red;
  -webkit-border-radius: 14px;
  -moz-border-radius: 14px;
  -o-border-radius: 14px;
  border-radius: 14px;
}
</style>
```

```html
<a href="http://ru.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank" class="SashaLove"> &nbsp;Стилизованная кнопка
<div class="SashaOrchidea" data-title="Спасибо&nbsp;за&nbsp;помощь!">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/HILLGIALLO_puntointerrogativo.png" width="21" height="21" border="0" alt="">
</div></a>
```

[image: Неудачный тултип]

Comment: А почему бы вам просто не использовать готовый плагин для этих целей http://lobianijs.com/site/lobibox ?

Comment: ну так же на bootstrap и на jquery есть отличные решения - http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tooltip&stacked=h     https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Comment: @LenovoID, Вы сами их опробовали? [Обе](http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/grPwXb) [выходят](http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/mPVrLd). Спасибо.

Comment: В Bootstrap можете использовать вот-это: `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({placement: 'auto';});` и ничего выходить не будет

Comment: В Bootstrap без указания позиции по умолчанию тултип будет показываться в `top`, но вы можете либо принудить использовать нужную позицию `placement: top | bottom | left | right | auto`, либо использовать `auto`, такие инструменты всегда имеют гибкие настройки, читайте документацию, уверен и на jQuery проблема решаема

Comment: Конечно пробовал - иначе не писал бы

Comment: @LenovoID, что Вы изменяли в настройках? Спасибо.

Comment: @Blacknife, [где-то ошибка](http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/WwxZQG) — `Unexpected token ;` . Спасибо.

Comment: можно и просто добавить аттрибут к объекту: `<img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="auto" ... />`, а вообще вы там скобки не закрыли http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxLGpr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо ув-мым @Blacknife, @Geyan и @dimaua, что потратили своё время на ответ к данному вопросу. Возможно, их решения не уступают в качестве, однако решил остановить свой выбор на JQuery-плагине **Tooltipster**. Поставленную в вопросе задачу он решает.

---

---

### Мини-обзор

- Достоинства — широкие возможности по кастомизации, см. [**сайт плагина**](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/). Кроссбраузерный, не тормозит показ страницы.
- Недостаток — на этом же офсайте напрочь отсутствуют примеры вида `Код — Результат`, поэтому придётся убить немного времени на освоение. Впрочем, ряд демо приведён в [**одной статье на русском**](http://ps-studio.info/load/tooltips/tooltipster_gibkij_i_rasshirjaemyj_jquery_plagin_dlja_sozdanija_sovremennykh_vsplyvajushhikh_podskazok/9-1-0-41).

---

---

### Код примера

Tooltipster не выбрасывает тултипы за окно, не только когда они простейшие. В демонстрируемом примере появляются отличные друг от друга всплывающие подсказки при наведении курсора и клике на икону с персонализированным оформлением и установлено время, в течение которого будет виден тултип — **http://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/RGzVmK**.

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var $SashaElement = $('.SashaTooltip');
     $SashaElement.tooltipster({
       content: 'Может, это ветерок Твои губы колышет',
       theme: ['tooltipster-punk-customized'],
       timer: 2000,
       side: ['bottom', 'top', 'right', 'left']
     });
     $SashaElement.tooltipster({
       content: 'Может, это я кричу Тебе, но Ты меня не слышишь',
       theme: 'tooltipster-punk',
       trigger: 'click',
       multiple: true,
       timer: 2000,
       side: ['bottom', 'top', 'right', 'left']
     });
   });
```

```css
body {
  background: gainsboro;
  margin-top: 7rem;
  padding-left: 7rem;
}
.tooltipster-sidetip.tooltipster-punk-customized .tooltipster-box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  background: #2a2a2a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=description content="">
  <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ps-studio.info/katalog/tooltips/1/tooltipster.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ps-studio.info/katalog/tooltips/1/tooltipster.bundle.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ps-studio.info/katalog/tooltips/1/sideTip/tooltipster-sideTip-punk.min.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/n9nm1qM.jpg" width="500" class="SashaTooltip">
</body>

</html>
```

---

---

### Демонстрация

[image: Sasha_Tooltipster]

Что видим:

- Если текст всплывающей подсказки не помещается в одну строку, он переносится на следующую.
- Когда места на [**стороне света**](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/140919) не остаётся, тултип появляется на другой. Отображение настраивается параметром `side`, в примере я задал ему значения `['bottom', 'top', 'right', 'left']`. Всплывающая подсказка по умолчанию будет снизу, если там нет места — сверху; когда недостаточно пространства как снизу, так и сверху — справа; ну и наконец, если ей некуда деться снизу, сверху и справа, она выведется слева.

---

---

За время съёмок ни одна всплывающая подсказка не выскочила за границу. В ещё более усложнённых моих реальных примерах с этим тоже порядок.

Answer (score 1):

Вот написал коротко, на мобильниках теперь 10px от правого борта появляется

```
$('.tooltip').on('mouseover', function(){
    var poz = $(this).position().left;
    var scr = $(window).width()-300;
    var leftt = scr-poz;
    if(leftt<-10){ var leftfinal = leftt-10; } else { var leftfinal = 0;    }
    $(this).children("span").css("left",leftfinal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Написал решение для себя на основе примера из интернета, где тултип просто бегал за мышкой, но при этом мог спокойно вылезть за пределы экрана.

Выкладываю на случай, если кому-то тоже нужно без левых плагинов. Есть вызов JQuery функции, хотя можно обойтись и без неё.

Суть: показываем div-подсказки в зависимости от расположения элемента на экране:

- если элемент правее центра - показываем подсказку слева
- если элемент левее центра - показываем подсказку справа

Аналогично по высоте. Чистая геометрия без всяких плагинов и зависимостей. А необходимую красоту можно и с CSS настроить.

```js
function tooltipenter(thisis, e) {
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  if (document.body.clientWidth - $(thisis).offset().left < document.body.clientWidth / 2)
    left = -1;
  if (document.body.clientHeight - $(thisis).offset().top < document.body.clientHeight / 2)
    top = -1;

  x = $(thisis).offset().left + left * 350 + left * 10 + thisis.offsetWidth / 2;
  y = $(thisis).offset().top + top * 350 + top * 10 + thisis.offsetHeight / 2;

  // Set the z-index of the current item,
  // make sure it's greater than the rest of thumbnail items
  // Set the position and display the image tooltip
  $(thisis).css('z-index', '15')
    .children("div.tooltip")
    .css({
      'top': y,
      'left': x,
      'display': 'block'
    });
}

function tooltipleave(thisis, e) {
  //  Reset the z-index and hide the image tooltip
  $(thisis).css('z-index', '1')
    .children("div.tooltip")
    .animate({
      "opacity": "hide"
    }, "fast");
}
```

```css
.tooltip {
  /* by default, hide it */
  display: none;
  /* allow us to move the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  /* align the image properly */
  padding: 8px 0 0 8px;
}

.tooltip span.overlay {
  /* the png image, need ie6 hack though */
  background: url(images/overlay.png) no-repeat;
  /* put this overlay on the top of the tooltip image */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 350px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='thumbnail-item' onmouseenter='tooltipenter(this,event);' onmouseleave='tooltipleave(this,event);'>
  Содержимое вашего элемента

  <div class="tooltip">
    Содержимое вашей всплывающей подказки/тултипа
    <img src="img/10-0.png" alt="" width="330" height="185" />;
    <span class="overlay"></span>";
  </div>";

</div>
```